# In Firefox 9 a HTML Table is hidden when it should be shown

Tags: html, firefox, html-table, hidden

Our Web application works fine in Firefox 8, but a few users have updated to Firefox 9 and now some HTML tables are hidden.

Firefox 9.0.1 is adding an extra hidden="" attribute to HTML.

So HTML like this:

```
<table id="form1:table1" class="Tbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Appears like this in the browser, using Firebug to view the rendered code:

```
<table id="form1:tableMyHistory" class="Tbl" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" hidden="">
```

The extra hidden="" seems to be added by Firefox 9.

Any ideas why Firefox 9.0.1 might be adding this extra attribute and hiding the tables?

Comment: could you post an online code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing like that happens on my Firefox. The odds are that the problem is created by JavaScript code on your page. To confirm this, test with JavaScript turned off.

If set the `hidden` property of an element node to `true` in JavaScript, then Firefox shows the HTML markup for the element as containing the attribute `hidden=""`.

Comment: Hi Jukka, 
Turning off JavaScript makes the tables appear! 
Thanks.

I just need to work out which script is causing the trouble.